# Limit FTP users to home directory on webmin

Tags: server, ftp, sftp, webmin

I'm Using ProFTP on webmin, Ubuntu 14.04.

I need to make FTP accounts for clients, who are limited to just a specified folder with no other access to the server.

I would prefer if it was secure.

I originally had it working by creating a new user under system->users, I was able to log in but also able to navigate the directory tree.

I saw on another post that it was the incorrect way to do this.

If it helps, I'm trying to recreate FTP Accounts -> New User on cPanel. Like [image]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to configure ProFTPD from webmin, but if you can SSH to the system (or access a terminal), edit `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf` to change the [`DefaultRoot`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DefaultRoot.html) directive to:

```
# Use this to jail all users in their homes 
DefaultRoot         ~
```

Restart the ftp service:

```
sudo service proftpd restart
```

You can provide exceptions to certain users/groups.

Comment: If I do this and try to login, I get 'connection refused' for all users.

Comment: @Anthony is the FTP service running? Check using `service proftpd status`. Can you post your configuration file to http://paste.ubuntu.com and add a link in the question? A `Connection Refused` indicates that the service isn't running, and if that happened after editing the configuration, some mistake might have happened.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7994212/ Basically what im doing is creating a system user in system->add user in webmin, with a home directory to a specific folder. Then trying to log in, works, but can navigate dir tree. Then I uncomment DefaultRoot, restart the service, and try to log in with the same user and get 'connection refused' each time.